# Find an element in DOM based on an attribute value

Tags: javascript, dom

Can you please tell me if there is any DOM API which search for an element with given attribute name and attribute value:

Something like:

```
doc.findElementByAttribute("myAttribute", "aValue");
```

Answer (score 230, accepted):

**Update:** In the past few years the landscape has changed drastically.  You can now reliably use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`, see [Wojtek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value#16775485) for how to do this.

There's no need for a jQuery dependency now.  If you're using jQuery, great...if you're not, you need not rely it on just for selecting elements by attributes anymore.

---

There's not a very short way to do this in vanilla javascript, but there are some solutions available.

[You do something like this, looping through elements and checking the attribute](http://snipplr.com/view/1853/get-elements-by-attribute/)

If a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is an option, you can do it a bit easier, like this:

```
$("[myAttribute=value]")
```

If the value isn't a valid [CSS identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) (it has spaces or punctuation in it, etc.), you need quotes around the value (they can be single or double):

```
$("[myAttribute='my value']")
```

You can also do `start-with`, `ends-with`, `contains`, etc...[there are several options for the attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).

Comment: I keep getting an empty array! I'm trying to grab an SVG by it's d attribute, and am trying $("[d=path]"); where 'path' is a variable containing the specific d-attribute I need. Has anyone tried doing this with svg paths?

Answer (score 789):

Modern browsers support native `querySelectorAll` so you can do:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-foo="value"]');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

Details about browser compatibility:

- http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t14
- http://caniuse.com/queryselector

You can use jQuery to support obsolete browsers (IE9 and older):

```
$('[data-foo="value"]');
```

Comment: in order to concretize the "modern" definition: http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelectorAll

Comment: It seems that value can not be a number or `SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified`

Comment: The selector should be: `'[data-foo="value"]'`

Comment: Any notes about perfomance? Is this faster then iterating over all nodes?

Comment: Note that the "jQuery" example might not be jQuery. It could be Chrome or Firefox implementation of  `$`. Read more about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244823/what-is-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript-if-not-jquery

Comment: What is "data-foo" ...and where is 'myAttribute' gone in this example?

Comment: This is the correct answer as 99.99% of browsers support this without JQuery. It's a shame stackoverflow doesn't let us depreciate old answers or notify people who answered them when they are out of date :(

Answer (score 120):

We can use attribute selector in DOM by using `document.querySelector()` and `document.querySelectorAll()` methods.

for yours:

```
document.querySelector("[myAttribute='aValue']");
```

and by using `querySelectorAll()`:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[myAttribute='aValue']");
```

In `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` methods we can select objects as we select in "CSS".

More about "CSS" attribute selectors in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: I had to remove inner quote marks like this document.querySelectorAll("selector[myAttribute=aValue]");

Answer (score 22):

Use query selectors. Examples:

```
document.querySelectorAll(' input[name], [id|=view], [class~=button] ')
```

`input[name]` Inputs elements with `name` property.

`[id|=view]` Elements with id that start with `view-`.

`[class~=button]` Elements with the `button` class.

Comment: hi is there a good ref. explaining these and more

Answer (score 18):

```
FindByAttributeValue("Attribute-Name", "Attribute-Value");
```

p.s. if you know exact element-type, you add 3rd parameter (i.e.`div, a, p ...etc...`):

```
FindByAttributeValue("Attribute-Name", "Attribute-Value", "div");
```

but at first, define this function:

```
function FindByAttributeValue(attribute, value, element_type)    {
  element_type = element_type || "*";
  var All = document.getElementsByTagName(element_type);
  for (var i = 0; i < All.length; i++)       {
    if (All[i].getAttribute(attribute) == value) { return All[i]; }
  }
}
```

p.s. updated per comments recommendations.

Comment: Why ?! You're looping all your DOM by doing this

Comment: This seems great - if you only have 5 elements on the page.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('[data-foo="value"]');` as proposed by @Wojtek Kruszewski on accepted awnser.

Comment: querySelector and querySelectorAll give you static nodes, the snippet by @T.Todua returns live nodes. That might be a reason to do it this way.

Comment: @ErikOosterwaal incorrect, `querySelectorAll` returns a static *collection of nodes*. The nodes inside are still live and would reflect any changes done to them, it's just that the collection does not update as the document updates. As opposed to, for example, `document.getElementsByClassName("foo")` which will return a collection that does live update. The nodes inside are otherwise the same as what you'd get from `document.querySelectorAll()`. To that effect, the snippet in this answer does *not* return a live collection but a single node.

Answer (score 13):

Here's how you can select using `querySelector`:

```
document.querySelector("tagName[attributeName='attributeValue']")
```

Answer (score 9):

[Amendment for Daniel De León's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62333543/3478762) 
It's possible to search with 
`^=` - filters Elements where id (or any other attr) starts with `view` keyword

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id^='view']")
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example , How to search images in a document by src attribute :

```
document.querySelectorAll("img[src='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/........jpg']");
```

Answer (score 8):

you could use getAttribute:

```
 var p = document.getElementById("p");
 var alignP = p.getAttribute("align");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Comment: He want to select the `p` element without using `id` or every `p` on the DOM (and test attributes)

Answer (score 8):

very simple, try this

```html
<h1>The Document Object</h1>
<h2>The querySelector() Method</h2>

<h3>Add a background color to the first p element:</h3>
<p>This is a p element.</p>
<p data-vid="1">This is a p element.</p>
<p data-vid="2">This is a p element.</p>
<p data-vid="3">This is a p element.</p>

<script>
  document.querySelector("p[data-vid='1']").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  document.querySelector("p[data-vid='2']").style.backgroundColor = "pink";
  document.querySelector("p[data-vid='3']").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function optCount(tagId, tagName, attr, attrval) {
    inputs = document.getElementById(tagId).getElementsByTagName(tagName);

    if (inputs) {
        var reqInputs = [];

        inputsCount = inputs.length;

        for (i = 0; i < inputsCount; i++) {

            atts = inputs[i].attributes;
            var attsCount = atts.length;

            for (j = 0; j < attsCount; j++) {

                if (atts[j].nodeName == attr && atts[j].nodeValue == attrval) {
                    reqInputs.push(atts[j].nodeName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("no such specified tags present");
    }
    return reqInputs.length;
}//optcount function closed
```

This is a function which is is used tu to select a particular tag with specific attribute value. The parameters to be passed are are the tag ID, then the tag name - inside that tag ID, and the attribute and fourth the attribute value.
This function will return the number of elements found with the specified attribute and its value.
You can modify it according to you.