# Is there a way to getElement xml by attribute?

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to grab an xml node by its attribute.

**edit**

I'm trying to retrieve an element by its attribute value using javascript xml instead of jquery.  Is there a simple method for this?

Comment: Don't do that. It's rude. Try to speak to the element before grabbing it by its attribute. Seriously, can you elaborate on your question? What did you try and what were the results?

Comment: I'm trying to get an element using javascript instead of jquery.find("node[id='1']")

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "Javascript:". That's what tags are for.

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery, you could always use `DomParser` or `loadXML` in the case of IE:
http://www.w3schools.com/Xml/xml_parser.asp

But seriously, use jQuery.

Comment: It might be worth it to check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value  Not sure if it's what you're asking for though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find a list of elements first, then filter by their attributes.

Check out my demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/silkster/eDP5V/

Comment: That's what I did.. I just wanted to see if there's another simplier way.

Answer (score 5):

It is really easy using jQuery. Suppose we have a string like this.

```
<document>
   <value type="people">
      <name>
         John
      </name>
   </value>
   <value type="vehicle">
      <name>
         Ford
      </name>
   </value>
</document>
```

Then

```
var xmlDocument = $.parseXML(str);
$(xmlDocument).find("value[type='people'] name").text()
```

We will get string 'John' back.

Answer (score 2):

I feel this justifies a new answer as it is JQuery Free

```
document.getElementsByAttribute = function(attribute, value, tagName, parentElement) {
    var children = ($(parentElement) || document.body).getElementsByTagName((tagName || '*'));
    return $A(children).inject([], function(elements, child) {
        var attributeValue = child.getAttribute(attribute);
        if(attributeValue != null) {
            if(!value || attributeValue == value) {
                elements.push(child);
            }
        }
        return elements;
    });
}
```

[source](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=83993)

---

it has been pointed out to me that I posted the wrong script.. hehe read [here](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=26744)

```
// document.getElementsByAttribute([string attributeName],[string attributeValue],[boolean isCommaHyphenOrSpaceSeparatedList:false])
document.getElementsByAttribute=function(attrN,attrV,multi){
    attrV=attrV.replace(/\|/g,'\\|').replace(/\[/g,'\\[').replace(/\(/g,'\\(').replace(/\+/g,'\\+').replace(/\./g,'\\.').replace(/\*/g,'\\*').replace(/\?/g,'\\?').replace(/\//g,'\\/');
    var
        multi=typeof multi!='undefined'?
            multi:
            false,
        cIterate=document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
        aResponse=[],
        attr,
        re=new RegExp(multi?'\\b'+attrV+'\\b':'^'+attrV+'$'),
        i=0,
        elm;
    while((elm=cIterate.item(i++))){
        attr=elm.getAttributeNode(attrN);
        if(attr &&
            attr.specified &&
            re.test(attr.value)
        )
            aResponse.push(elm);
    }
    return aResponse;
}
```

Comment: are you sure this is a jquery free answer?  `$(parentElement)` ... ?

Comment: whoops! i was looking at two on the same forums.... http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=26744 I tested both.. seems to work for me.

Comment: So not exactly jQuery free, but jQuery lite for sure - no extensions/plugins/modules...

Comment: Thanks anyways, I just looped through elements and compared the attributes to get the result.

I just wanted to know if there was something more simplier like jquery.

Comment: there is a jquery free one... the editor butchers the code.. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

jquery can do this very easily. http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/

Comment: I'm constructing an xml on the fly, jquery does not work well with IE.