# Trying to remove a certain element from a XML file

Tags: javascript, xml, element

Have been struggling with this for a while. For some reason nothing works for me.

I have a xml file like this:

```
<messages>

    <message>
        <name>John</name>
        <content>Hello</content>
    </message>

    <message>
        <name>dd</name>
        <content>Whats up</content>
    </message>

</messages>
```

Now I am trying to write a JavaScript button, that removes a certain element "message".
What I have tried to differentiate between "message" elements:

- Have each element "message" include an element "id". That didn't help because I don't know if it's possible to identify a certain element by only knowing one of its subelements.
- Have each element "message" own an attribute. And then delete the element that owns a certain attribute id="1" for example.

I think the latter idea is better, but I can't figure out how to delete an element by attribute.

Am I missing something completely obvious here that would make everything easier?

Thanks

EDIT: I now know what happened. It deleted the element from the variable, but I want it to delete it from messages.xml. Modified data wasn't being sent back to the file itself. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083341/is-there-a-way-to-getelement-xml-by-attribute