# How to write a function like `document.getElementsWithAttributeName("attr-name")`?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Could someone tell me how to write a function: `getElementsWithAttributeName("attr-name")`?

It should return all elements from the current `document` that contain the attribute `attr-name`.

Also, how do I add this function to the document as well?

Any response will be much appreciated.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('[attr-name]');`

Comment: @RobW why are you commenting?Cant you answer directly

Comment: What have you tried so far? What was the problem that you had with your code?

Comment: and [Find an element in DOM based on an attribute value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2694640/218196)

Comment: document.getElementsByAttribute = Element.prototype.getElementsByAttribute = function(attr) {
    var nodeList = this.getElementsByTagName('*');
    var nodeArray = [];

    for (var i = 0, node; node = nodeList[i]; i++) {
        if ( node.getAttribute(attr) ) nodeArray.push(node);
    }

    return nodeArray;
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a method to `document` just like this:

```
document.fnName = function(args){ ... };
```

As Rob W pointed out in the comments, you can just use the existing `document.querySelectorAll()` method and pass a css selector. If you *really* wanted this to work like `getElementsByAttributeName("attr-name")` you could do this:

```
document.getElementsByAttributeName = function(attrName){
    return document.querySelectorAll('[' + attrName+']'); 
};
```

Note, this is IE8+ only. (*`document.querySelectorAll()` requires IE9 for CSS3 selectors however.*)

**references**:

- [MDN: `querySelectorAll()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)
- [CSS-Tricks: The Skinny on CSS Attributes](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: thanks very much. this meets my purpose.