# HTML Remove Label for input without ID

Tags: javascript, html, label

I've got a label for an input. Defined like:

```
<label for"idofparentelement">innerHTML</label>
```

Found nothing where the label for hasn't got an id.

How can i remove it with JavaScript without giving an id.

Comment: What do you want to do? its sounds so simple that my mind tries to debate there something behind it.

Comment: I've got an element. An Input. This input has an ID.
So i've got a label too. the label hasn't got an id. How can i remove the label for my input element ?

Comment: @user3564050 — So your question is "How can I find an element in the DOM based on the value of its `for` attribute?"?

Comment: Duplicate: [Find an element in DOM based on an attribute value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value)

Comment: doesn't work for me ^^

Comment: @user3564050 — It should work for you. I've no way to tell what is wrong with your implementation of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove element with specific attribute Use this function:

```
function removeElem(tag,atr,vl)
{
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    vl=vl.toLowercase();
    for (var i = 0; i<els.length; i++) {
    var elem=els[i];
    if(elem.getAttribute(atr)){
    if ( elem.getAttribute(atr).toString().toLowercase()==vl){
    elem.remove();
    return;
    }
    }
    }
}
```

and First of all
Change your `html` like:

```
<label for="idofparentelement">innerHTML</label>
```

Now for your case Use this as: `removeElem('label','for','idofparentelement');`

Here is the working:

## `Fiddle`

Hope it'll help you cheers :)!!

Comment: @user3564050 I'm glad that I could help you. +1.

Comment: Well using `""` or `''` for concatenation and to make passing arguments as strings is useless.

Comment: @RahilWazir Then How will you pass arguments? May I know that?

Comment: @VedantTerkar You are passing the arguments correctly. What I mean is Just use your parameter in your function definition like this `elem.getAttribute(atr)`. Using `""` or `''` either side is just an empty string it doesn't make passed parameters as string.