# Find all tags where exist “display: none”, and add attribute aria-hidden="true"

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio-2013

This should be done with Visual Studio, regular expression find and replace.

For example:

```
<tr id="ID1" style="display: none;"></tr>
```

replace with

```
<tr id="ID1" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"></tr>
```

Or

```
<span id="ID2" class="someClass" style="color:red; display: none;"></span>
```

replace with

```
<span id="ID2" class=" someClass" style="color:red; display: none;" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

I have regular expression to find all tags with display: none:

```
(<[^>]+)display: none;
```

But I do not now how to include new attribute in this tags?
It should work for every tag, no matter how many attributes tag have.

Comment: I would be better to use XML DOM functions to edit the HTML.

Comment: Use this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or for a strict answer to your question:

replace:

```
(<[^>]+)display: none;[^"]*"
```

with:

```
$& aria-hidden="true"
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know some good books/pages where can I learn stuff like this?