# How do you use the query selector to select a general phrase?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'll start off by showing you the current code

```
var CurrItem = document.querySelector('input[value="Insane 4"]').click();
SetTimeout(function(){CurrItem.Click();,10000}
```

This is what it looks like, I assumed it would select a input text of "Insane 4.." and then click it.

Now what it actually did was absolutely nothing.

I'm trying to click the object by input so I can automate a sell system to select a Object named "Insane #" then click another button with the input of "Sell"

[This is what I'm trying to click within the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfc4g.jpg)

[This is the code for the above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWcLK.png)

**Things to keep in mind:**

RowID Always changes.

I'm going to be doing more then "4" (4 - 11)

I'm using TamperMonkey to run the script.

Comment: Where in that screenshot do you see an `input` element?

Comment: Can't you assign an ID to the element at creation? Also, input[value=someValue] searches for input elements  (<input>) with value = someValue. For some guidance see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value/16775485#16775485

Comment: Whoops. grabbed it from another script of mine i thought the input was the actual Text Value within it, how would I select it?

Comment: Can you show more of the page/html?  It looks like the 'a' tag in your html handles the click so you want to simulate a click on this.  Unless you can select by RowID you may need to return all rows and search inner html for your text 'Insane 4'.

Comment: Would it be possible to do something along these lines
    var CurrItem = document.querySelectorAll(document.GetElementByID('b').innerhtml("Insane 4"));

Comment: the b has the actual innerhtml i would need to look at specifically

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion: learn some fundamentals of programming before writing any code, specifically about method and method calls.

In Javascript, function is a first class object, quoting from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function):

> In computer science, a programming language is said to support
>   first-class functions (or function literal) if it treats functions as
>   first-class objects. Specifically, this means that the language
>   supports constructing new functions during the execution of a program,
>   storing them in data structures, passing them as arguments to other
>   functions, and returning them as the values of other functions.

`setTimeout` accepts `function` as its first parameter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

`var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(code, [delay]);`

Therefore, you need to declare a function that calls `.click()` and then pass it to `setTimeout`. I won't directly fix your code, but will give you a general syntax to get you started:

```
var doClick = function() {
  //Your code to .click() here
}

setTimeout(doClick, 10000);
```

Comment: I use it the way its shown for most things and it works completely fine.