# Unable to get an element by attribute value with a decimal ( . )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my Html Snippet

```
<div class="style" title="Demo.1"></div>
<div class="style" title="Sample"></div>
```

I am trying to get an  html element using the selector

`$('[title=Demo.1]').html()`

and i got this error message

> jquery-1.8.3.js:4680 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [title=Demo.1]

but it is working for `$('[title=Sample]').html()`

I think it is because of the decimal point "." 
Is there any other way to solve this

Comment: The relevant part from the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: Another dupe target: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need quotes on the value:

```
$('[title="Demo.1"]').html()
```

Example:

```js
console.log($('[title="Demo.1"]').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="style" title="Demo.1">Demo1</div>
<div class="style" title="Sample">Sample</div>
```

Comment: Yes its working, thank you  :)

Answer (score 0):

The [Attribute Equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) use valid identifers or quoted strings to target the appropriate element by its value, however quoted strings are generally more reliable when targeting non-identifier attributes like this one.

```
// This will target any elements that have a title attribute that is exactly "Demo.1"
$('[title="Demo.1"]').html();
```