# javascript set focus on contenteditable area using data- attribute and value

Tags: javascript, attributes, focus, contenteditable

I've got a template full of contenteditable areas that may or maynot already have id attributes.  The one difference is that they all contain unique data- values so I'd like to use them to help me target/focus my cursor programically on specific areas for editing.

If I store the data- value in a var this way:

```
textArea[0] = this.getAttribute("data-id");
```

and my user looses focus on the contenteditable area they are currently work in, how can I force the cursor back to it?

```
document.[data-id=textArea[0]].focus();
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you create a small fiddle example? Right now it is very broad

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2f47rygq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use vanilla js, you can write something like:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-id="' + dataId + '"]')[0].focus()
```

(check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value/16775485#16775485) on how to select elements by attribute)

If you can use Jquery you can just have:

```
$('[data-id="' + dataId + '"]').focus();
```

You can check also [this fiddle](http://jsbin.com/repako/edit?js,console,output) in case