# how to replace href link using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have lots of pages with lots of links. I want to replace some specific links with another link.

what I wish to do here is find the `href` attribute of `<a>` and replace it with desired link

Here is the HTML code

```
<div class="one">
     <div class="item">
         <a href="somelink.com">click</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

and I want to change HTML to

```
<div class="one">
     <div class="item">
         <a href="replacedlink.com">click</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way could be is to use the href value to find the anchor

```js
var a = document.querySelector('a[href="somelink.com"]');
if (a) {
  a.setAttribute('href', 'replacedlink.com')
}
```

```html
<a href="somelink.com" title="this link">
</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$('.item a').attr('href').replace('somelink.com', "replacedlink.com");
```

**OR**

```
$(".item a[href='somelink.com']").attr("href", "replacedlink.com");
```

With jQuery 1.6 and above you should use:

```
$(".item a[href='somelink.com']").prop("href", "replacedlink.com");
```

Comment: The .replace isn't needed! You can just add to the attr function as per the other answers below.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$(".item a[href='somelink.com']").attr('href','replacedlink.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.attr` attribute to do this. Please follow below code::

```
$('.item a[href="somelink.com"]').attr('href', 'replacedlink.com');
```

For more information related to `.attr` attribute please go through this [link](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Answer (score 0):

Here try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/2sqxaxqs/

```
$('a.btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    var newHref = 'http://www.google.com';
  $('a.theLink').attr('href', newHref);
})
```

You can target the href using jQuery's attr.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a[href="somelink.com"]').attr('href', 'replacedlink.com');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
     <div class="item">
         <a href="somelink.com">click</a>
     </div>
</div>
```