# Click All Javascript Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I run:

javascript:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('subscribe_follow'); 

for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) { 
   inputs[i].click(); 
}
```

to click all buttons with the class `class="subscribe_follow"`,
it also clicks all buttons with the class `class="subscribe_follow ng-hide"`.

How do I only click the exact class?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `not` operator.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.subscribe_follow:not(.ng-hide)');
```

`.subscribe_follow:not(.ng-hide)` selector selects all the elements with the class `subscribe_fellow` but which do not have the `ng-hide` class.

**jQuery**

```
$('.subscribe_follow:not(.ng-hide)');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `not` operator as suggested by Sushanth. The disadvantage here is that you'd have to mention every class that is supposed to be excluded, which may be a pain depending on the number of different classes that you might be using on the same elements.

**I recommend declaring classes with the sole purpose of applying js, or targeting the elements by a different attribute that you could set in your HTML.**

Here you can find more about alternative targeting:

[Find an element in DOM based on an attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value)

Comment: Man I was writing exactly that when you posted the question damn

Comment: We were synced lol you typed faster though, good you realised. +1