# How i search the dom with pure javascript for find a custom link attribute?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

Suppose i have a link such as

```
<a class="like_button" href="#" action_click="LikePost">I Like It</a>
```

How can i search the dom via pure JavaScript to scan the html for the `action_click="LikePost"`
The code below doest not work for me

```
document.getElementsByTagName('action_click')
```

I feel though that a regular expression might needed.

Comment: Tag != Attribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find an element in DOM based on an attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2694640/5447994)

Answer (score 3):

Use `document.querySelector`

```
document.querySelector('[action_click="LikePost"]');
```

And if there are multiple such elements, use `document.querySelectorAll` which will return a live `HTMLCollection`.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[action_click="LikePost"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `querySelector()` like that:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('[action_click="LikePost"]'));
```

```html
<a class="like_button" href="#" action_click="LikePost">I Like It</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one element with that attribute then `querySelector` works.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('[action_click="LikePost"]');
console.log(elem);
```

```html
<a class="like_button" href="#" action_click="LikePost">
```

But if you have multiple elements then `querySelectorAll` is what you need:

```js
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('[action_click="LikePost"]');
console.log(elem);
```

```html
<a class="like_button" href="#" action_click="LikePost">
<a class="like_button" href="#" action_click="LikePost">
<a class="like_button" href="#" action_click="LikePost">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped!
Im using this JavaScript code within a python script, but even if JavaScript syntax is correct, the script refuses to run complaining about a syntax error.

`driver.execute_script("window.a = document.querySelectorAll('[action_click="LikePost"]');")`
I think im missing something