# Check whole page to see if a div with specific data-id exists in plain JS

Tags: javascript

I would like to test if a page has the following div.

```
<div class="evs-embedded-card" data-id="10">some text</div>
```

How can I test to see if there is a div present that has both `class="evs-embedded-card"` and `data-id="10"`?

Comment: Did you try anything ? what was the problem ?

Comment: Already answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) by specifying the class and attribute selector for the custom attribute without any space in between them.

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.evs-embedded-card[data-id="10"]');
console.log(el);
```

```html
<div class="evs-embedded-card" data-id="10">some text</div>
```