# Search HTML elements for specific attribute values

Tags: html, attributes, tags

I need to search my website for all instances where an attribute value contains a certain keyword. For example: In the following snippet I have an aria-label which contains the word taco. I would crawl my site and find all pages which contains the word "taco". Does anyone know a site or tool which can do this?

```
<a href="eattaco.html" aria-label="eat a taco">hungry?</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a jQuery selector to do this.

e.g.

`$("[aria-label~='taco']")`

will return all the elements whose aria-label contains the word 'taco'.

See this answer here: [Find an element in DOM based on an attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value)

Comment: Thank you Robbie. However, I am looking for a way to apply this jquery to a sitewide search. Problem is we have 500 plus dynamic pages in which this attribute is pulling from a database and the format in DB is unreadable.