# Get div value from class name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a very large HTML that contains lots of `div`s with the same name, I want a way to only filter or extract that value from that `div`.

Here is an example:

```
<td class="last">
  <div class="container-relative">
    <div class="name" title="&quot;User&quot; <John Appleseed>"></div>
    <div class="date">9/17/2019</div>
    <div class="tool"></div>
  </div>
</td>
```

I need to extract only what's between `<John Appleseed>`, in this case is 'John Appleseed'.

Comment: `value` ? You mean the title of the div ? So you have a lot of `div` with same `class` attribute but different `title` attributes ? And you want to get all those title attributes values ? And do what with them ?

Comment: `getAttribute`. That's what you're looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find an element in DOM based on an attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value)

Comment: @MihaiT yes, that's correct I want to extract the title. The title is different for each div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to take all the elements with class `name`, then get the `title` attribute with [`getAttribute`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp), and finally use a regular expression to match text between `<>`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.name').forEach(item => {
  let title = item.getAttribute('title');
  console.log(title.match(/\<.*\>/));
});
```

```html
<td class="last">
  <div class="container-relative">
    <div class="name" title="&quot;User&quot; <John Appleseed>"></div>
    <div class="date">9/17/2019</div>
    <div class="tool"></div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var divs=[];
for(i=0,j=0,obj=document.getElementsByClassName("name");i<obj.length;i++)
    if(obj[i].title.includes("John Appleseed") && 
    /* obj[i].title.split("\"")[2].trim()=="<John Appleseed>" && */
    obj[i].tagName.toLowerCase()=="div"){
        divs[j++]=obj[i];
    }
console.log(divs);
```

Answer (score -3):

separate your div using div ID. Then get your respective div using that value of ID. Then in javascript you can use getElementByID.

Answer (score -4):

You can use Xpath,

```
.//div[contains(@class, 'Test')]
```

Then extract you required text from it.