# React: Get a list of tags by attribute values

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a text which displays some information upon mouse hover. For example, I have three  tags with following information

```
<div class="body main-seq" style="display: inline;">
    <span prob="67.8">
        Foo
    </span>
    <span prob="67.8;34.6">
        Bar
    </span>
    <span prob="67.8;34.6;52.7">
        Hello
    </span>
</div>
```

On a browser, it will look something like this

`FooBarHello`

Basically, when user hovers a mouse on first bit of the text (the one that corresponds to "Bar"), I want to bold all the span tags that contain "34.6" in its "prob" attribute. In this case, it would have to bold "BarHello", but leave "Foo" as it is.

After doing some Google search, this task seems pretty trivial in Javascript or jQuery, and can be done by doing something like so,

`$("span[prob*='34.6']")` (along with onMouseOver event or something similar)

[Find an element in DOM based on an attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value)

However, I've seen many posts saying I should absolutely try to avoid using jQuery in React because React and jQuery has conflicting philosophy (React renders DOM every time the data changes whereas jQuery directly manipulates DOM). Please correct me if I am wrong though.

So my question is, how can I achieve this in React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perhaps do something like this in React:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function MyComponent(props) {

  const [ isHovered, setIsHovered ] = useState(false);

  const onMouseEnter = () => {
    setIsHovered(true);
  }

  const onMouseLeave = () => {
    setIsHovered(false);
  }

  const spans = [
    { text: 'Foo', probs: [67.8] },
    { text: 'Bar', probs: [67.8, 34.6] },
    { text: 'Hello', probs: [67.8, 34.6, 52.7] }
  ];

  return (
    <div
      class="body main-seq"
      style="display: inline;"
      onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
    >
      {spans.map(({ text, probs }) => {
        const isBold = isHovered && probs.includes(34.6);
        return (
          <span style={{ fontWeight: isBold ? 'bold' : 'normal'; }}>
            {text}
          </span>
        );
      }}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching this the wrong way, but it's a great exercise in "thinking in React".

You basically have these `span` tags that store number values. Each of them have the same responsibilities:

1. Store a list of number values
2. When clicked, set the new "criteria" values
3. let the others know that they should check if they should be bold or not

So let's call this component `SpanComponent`. We want a structure like this:

```
 export const SpanComponent = ({ values, activeValues, setActiveValues, children }) => {
  const isBold = checkForMatchingValues(values, activeValues) // returns true or false
  const onMouseEnter = event => {
    setActiveValues(values)
  }
  return (
    <span style={{ fontWeight: isBold ? 'bold' : 'normal' }} onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}>{children}</span>
  )
}
```

Then in our main component we can manage these as so:

```
export const MainComponent = () => {
  const [activeValues, setActiveValues] = useState([]) // empty array as default value

  return (
    <SpanComponent values={[68.8]} activeValues={activeValues} setActiveValues={setActiveValues}/>
    <SpanComponent values={[68.8, 34.6]} activeValues={activeValues} setActiveValues={setActiveValues}/>
    <SpanComponent values={[68.8, 34.6, 52.7]} activeValues={activeValues} setActiveValues={setActiveValues}/>
  )
}
```