# clicking a button in javascript without button id or class

Tags: javascript, html, applescript

I'm trying to use AppleScript to click a button on a webpage, however the button I need to click doesn't have an ID or Class, and it's located inside a div/input tag:

```
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;position:absolute;width:100px;right:20px"><input style="padding:4px;height:2em;width:100px" type="submit" value="save" tabindex="-1"></div>
<input style="padding:4px;height:2em;width:100px" type="submit" value="save" tabindex="-1">
```

I tried using querySelector, but it didn't work. How do I go about clicking this button?

Comment: You've tagged this [javascript] but you're talking about AppleScript. As far as I know they are different languages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find an element in DOM based on an attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value)

Comment: Heretic Monkey they are different languages, but in AppleScript there is a "do Javascript" command, which allows you to use Javascript to interact with web pages. I used it successfully to input text into a search bar. I should have included the [AppleScript] tag as well though, the problem was with AppleScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case an attribute selector would work fine, I'd imagine.

`document.querySelector('input[value="save"]')`

More information from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to use your example, coupled with a helpful article I found elsewhere, and the solution was: do JavaScript " document.querySelector(\"input[value='save']\").click();" Thank you for your help!