# Select an object property within an attribute of the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, object, attributes

I looked at this thread but it didn't help: [Find an element in DOM based on an attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value)

I need a Vanilla JS solution to select a username that is in a custom attribute of an `<a>` tag in the DOM. I used `const users = document.querySelectorAll('a[metadata]')` which returns a NodeList of all the `<a>` tags with all their attributes. If I type `console.log(users[0])`, I get:

```
<a href="#" class="btn-normal" metadata="
{
'username':'johnny134',
'category':'shoes',
'summary':'Just a guy called Johnny',
'userId':1223432432
}"
</a>
```

To access the username, I have tried `const usernames = document.querySelectorAll('a[metadata="username"]');` but just get back undefined. I think my issue is that username is in an object and I can't figure out how to select it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that `document.querySelectorAll` returns a list of *elements* that match the given query, not a list of the values of attributes of those elements that you specify in the query.

From `const users = document.querySelectorAll('a[metadata]')`, you can get the `metadata` attribute of, say, the first element, like so:

```js
const metadata0 = users[0].getAttribute("metadata");
```

And then, since it's a JSON string, you parse it:

```js
const user0 = JSON.parse(metadata0);
```

Now you can use `user0` like a regular JavaScript object:

```js
user0.username
// johnny134
```

---

P.S. The JSON in the metadata attribute is not valid, and you may get an error when you try to parse it. Use double quotes in JSON, not single quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer- the separation of getElement and getAttribute, along with the parsing of the JSON is spot on. It works for me.