# Javascript selector for element with attribute with spaces

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I have a button with the attribute of `aria-label="Sign In"`. I'm trying to select it with `document.querySelector('button[aria-label=Sign In]')` but that returns `Uncaught DOMException: Document.querySelector: 'button[aria-label=Sign In]' is not a valid selector`. Please help!

Comment: Try with button[aria-label="Sign In"], you need to wrap it in

Comment: You were a Google search away from [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2694640/383904)....

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I tried Googling it but it didn't bring anything up because I was searching for select attribute with spaces

Comment: @ajarrow Google is against you if you complicate the search query ;) I googled for: *"js select elements by attribute page:stackoverflow"* and bam. First result on top. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a space in an attribute selector you must enclose it in quotes otherwise it is treated as a descendant selector.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors

```js
let b = document.querySelector('button[aria-label="Sign In"]');
console.log(b)
```

```html
<button aria-label="Sign In">Hi Sign In!</button>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector  additional information on selectors here

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2694640/383904 of cumulative 1000+ votes

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Similar yes but not specific to the cause and the descendent selector that resulted and why.

Comment: PS, button should always have a `type` attribute. Just for the sake of muscle memory. `type="button"` since by default it's `type="submit"`

Comment: Yep I see lots of input and button without a type, and in this case it might be a submit button based purely on the OP code so I left it without, but good call out there @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: It's... debatable whether it's actually treated as a descendant combinator in that context but it is a syntax error all the same. Namely, browsers that support case-sensitivity flags *don't* treat it as one, but will still throw because the token `In` isn't a valid case-sensitivity flag. As for browsers that don't, who knows? Maybe they treat it as a descendant combinator, maybe they treat it as whitespace and throw on the `In` because they were expecting a `]` instead.

Answer (score 2):

use single or double quotes :

```
document.querySelector('button[aria-label="Sign In"]')
document.querySelector("button[aria-label='Sign In']")
```

OR escape the quotes if you same quotes for enclosing and representation :

```
document.querySelector("button[aria-label=\"Sign In\"]")
document.querySelector('button[aria-label=\'Sign In\']')
```

or use literal:

```
document.querySelector(`button[aria-label='Sign In']`)
```

You can use any of the approach

Comment: I tried single quotes but that doesn't work unless you have double quotes outside of that. Thanks!

Comment: you have to escape quotes if you use single , see the full available option @ajarrow