# How to use javascript to delete custom attribute elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

The HTML as follows:

[image: screenshot]

**What I know:**

- TAG name is random ;
- `id` is random, also `class`;
- The common attribute is that they all have `classname` attr.

How should I remove them just use `js`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find an element in DOM based on an attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value)

Comment: It looks like you are violating lots of HTML rules for custom elements. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.removeAttribute` in the HTMLelement, here is an example:

```js
function removeClassname() {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[classname]')

  elements.forEach((element) => {
    element.removeAttribute('classname')
  })
}
```

```css
[classname] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div classname="abc">asdasd</div>
<button classname="abc">asdasd</button>
<p classname="abc">asdasd</p>

<button onclick="removeClassname()">Remove classname</button>
```