# Checkbox be checked, unique custom attribute

Tags: javascript, checkbox

How can a checkbox be checked using JavaScript: (cpf="45258236978")

```
<input type="checkbox" style="vertical-align: bottom;" id_pasta="26337043" cpf="45258236978" id_tarefa="122525428">
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check/Uncheck checkbox with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206565/check-uncheck-checkbox-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```js
 document.getElementById("yourCheckboxID").checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let check = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
    for (var ii = 0; ii < check[i].attributes.length; ii++) {
        if (check[i].attributes[ii].nodeValue == '45258236978') {
            check[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```