# Is it possible to target a label with JavaScript using the for part of the label?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to target a label which is part of a CMS system.  The simplest way would be to use "for"

I can target the input instead and then the sibling, I just thought I would ask if this is possible.

The main reason I want to do this is to remove the `(+£5.00)`

```
<input type="radio" autocomplete="off" name="product_option[54]" value="107" id="option-value-107" onchange="doAjaxPrice(108,'#option-54');">
<label for="option-value-107">1kg(+£5.00)</label>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find an element in DOM based on an attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value)

Comment: @Justinas yes I think so, thank you.  I just didn't know what to call them.  Is "attribute value" the correct name?

Comment: Yes, `for` is attribute, and `option-value-107` is this attribute's value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can :

```
document.querySelector('label[for="option-value-107"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use square brackets and specify attribute and it's value to select an element

```
document.querySelector('label[for*=option-value-107]')
```

Comment: Your selector will select unwanted elements. E.g. `for="root-option-value-107"`