# Add css .selected class name back to html table with localstorage when page is auto refreshed

Tags: php, jquery, css-selectors, local-storage

I have confirmed that localstorage is storing the row id with

```
sessionStorage.setItem(rowId, 'true');
```

I am trying to re-apply the css .selected class name back to the row id when the page is refreshed with

Main purpose is to keep the selected row highlighted when page is reloaded

```
if (localStorage.getItem('1') === 'true' || localStorage.getItem('2') === 'true') {
                                             
}
```

```
.selected {
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px #FF0000;
        border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

### --
Java function that highlights the table row when clicked and stores the row id with sessionStorage.setItem(rowId, 'true');

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
highlight_row();
function highlight_row() {

    var table = document.getElementById('display-table');
    var cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        // Take each cell
        var cell = cells[i];
        // do something on onclick event for cell
        cell.onclick = function () {
            // Get the row id where the cell exists
            var rowId = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
            var rowsNotSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for (var row = 0; row < rowsNotSelected.length; row++) {
                rowsNotSelected[row].style.backgroundColor = "";
                rowsNotSelected[row].classList.remove('selected');
            }
            var rowSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[rowId];
            rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            rowSelected.className += " selected";
    
            sessionStorage.setItem(rowId, 'true');
            //alert(rowId);   
            
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value

Comment: You are setting `sessionStorage` so you have to get the value from the sessionStorage but you try to get the value from localStorage. See [MDN examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) - Right under the examples is a section "Saving text between refreshes" which should be similar to your question.

Comment: @Uwe I was testing between both, but I am using sessionstorage as the solution.  I do understand the "Saving text between refreshes" with sessionstorage I have that part working with a text field, but how to re-apply -----> var rowSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[rowId];
            rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            rowSelected.className += " selected";

Comment: @ L1some please share your html markup of your table where you want to set the class.

Comment: <table width="100%" class="sortable" id="display-table">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to replace this line

```js
// that would add multiple entries per click on different rows 
// eg: 1: true, 3: true, 47: true
sessionStorage.setItem(rowId, "true");
```

with

```js
sessionStorage.setItem('rowId', rowId);
```

That will overwrite the value for last clicked rowId and you don't have to check for all possible rows / key value pairs.

To set the classes use the code you already wrote in your click handler.
Put that block after your for loop.

```js
// your for loop
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { 
   ...
}

// new code
// check if rowId key exist
// if rowId does not exist null is returned - so we can check for that

if ( sessionStorage.getItem('rowId') !== null ) {
      rowSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[sessionStorage.getItem('rowId')];
      rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      rowSelected.className += " selected";
}
```

Comment: that worked  className is being applied after page reload, thank you so much for helping with this.